# Stopping and Starting Runnable freezes application for 2-10 sec

Tags: java, audio, runnable

The main core of my application is a Runnable which allows audio feedback (user speaks and hears his voice back ), while that feedback is controlled by three Jsliders (audio delay, volume, pitch shifting ).

The problem is that when the first JSlider (Audio Delay) is handled,  the program freezes for a while (2-10 sec). In my opinion, that occurs because when handled, the Runnable stops(), and a new is started.

I use the **TarsosDSP** package. The Runnable is called Dispatcher.

These 3 Jsliders define/feed 3 variables, which are used by some Class objects that are used by the Dispatcher, in order for the manipulation(delay,volume,pitch shift) of the feeback to take place.

The 3 variables:

*currentFactor* (Jslider for pitch shifting), *sampleRate* (..for audio delay), *gainValue* (..for volume)

**Sequence of events:**

**1.** click a Trial button --> Creation of a Dispatcher (audio feedback starts)

`

```
trial.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        // Definition of the 2 variables: currentFactor and sampleRate, from the Jsliders(freqshift, sldelay)
        currentFactor = gridbagLayout.freqshift.getValue() / 100.0;
        int delayFactor = gridbagLayout.sldelay.getValue();
        double df = (double) delayFactor / (double) 100;

        sampleRate = 44100 * df;

        AudioFormat format;
        try {
            format = new AudioFormat(44100, 8, 1, true, true);

            // RateTransposer class is used from the runnable Dispatcher 
            // in order to alter the feedback's pitch, with CurrentFactor's value                           
            rateTransposer = new RateTransposer(currentFactor);
            gain = new GainProcessor(1.0);

            // Here, the 3rd variable gainValue is used by GainProcessor
            //  class (gain), which is used from the Dispatcher, 
            // in order to alter the feedback's volume, according to gainValue's value                                                             
            gain.setGain(gridbagLayout.volume.getValue() / 1.0);

            audioPlayer = new AudioPlayer(format);

            // Here, an other class (wsola) used by Dispatcher, is 
            // constructed by SampleRate and CurrentFactor variables  
            wsola = new WaveformSimilarityBasedOverlapAdd(Parameters
                    .musicDefaults(currentFactor, sampleRate));

            DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(
                    TargetDataLine.class, format);

            Mixer.Info mixerInfo = Shared.getMixerInfo(false, true)
                    .get(1);
            Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo);
            line = (TargetDataLine) mixer.getLine(dataLineInfo);
            line.open(format, wsola.getInputBufferSize());

            // A line for audio input starts. 
            line.start();
            final AudioInputStream stream = new AudioInputStream(line);

            // A Dispatcher runnable is created from WSOLA 
            dispatcher = new AudioDispatcher(stream, wsola
                    .getInputBufferSize(), wsola.getOverlap());

            // RateTransposer, GainProcessor, WSOLA class objects are attached 
            // to Dispatcher
            wsola.setDispatcher(dispatcher);
            dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(wsola);
            dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(rateTransposer);
            dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(gain);
            dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(audioPlayer);


            Thread t = new Thread(dispatcher);

            // All process() methods of the attached objects (RateTransposer, 
            // GainProcessor, WSOLA and more) are executed. That enables
            // the update of the 3 variables, thus alteration of the feedback                          
            t.start();

        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

**2.** After that, user controlls the three Jsliders. ( audio feedback is altered)

When i control the Delay Jslider :

```
public ChangeListener delaySettingChangedListener = new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {

        int delayFactor = sldelay.getValue();

        df = (double) delayFactor / (double) 100;

        // Here, sampleRate variable is updated
        panelbuttons.sampleRate = 44100 * df;
        // And then, I stop the current runnable Dispatcher, and start a new one, 
        //according to the updated variable               
        startFile();
    }
};
```

Code for StartFile() :

```
private void startFile() {
    // stop the current thread
    if (panelbuttons.dispatcher != null)
        panelbuttons.dispatcher.stop();

    if (timer == null) {
        timer = new Timer(400, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // and start a new one, after some time, in order
                // for the previous runnable to end/withdraw
                startFile0();
            }
        });
    }
    timer.stop();
    timer.setRepeats(false);
    timer.start();

}
```

Code for StartFile0, which is almost same as Trial button listener method :

```
private void startFile0() {


    AudioFormat format;
    try {
        format = new AudioFormat(44100, 8, 1, true, true);
        panelbuttons.rateTransposer = new RateTransposer(
                panelbuttons.currentFactor);
        panelbuttons.audioPlayer = new AudioPlayer(format);

        panelbuttons.wsola = new WaveformSimilarityBasedOverlapAdd(
                Parameters.musicDefaults(panelbuttons.currentFactor,
                        panelbuttons.sampleRate)
        );

        DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(
                TargetDataLine.class, format);
        TargetDataLine line;

        Mixer.Info mixerInfo = Shared.getMixerInfo(false, true).get(1);
        Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo);

        line = (TargetDataLine) mixer.getLine(dataLineInfo);
        line.open(format, panelbuttons.wsola.getInputBufferSize());

        line.start();
        final AudioInputStream stream = new AudioInputStream(line);
        panelbuttons.dispatcher = new AudioDispatcher(stream,
                panelbuttons.wsola.getInputBufferSize(),
                panelbuttons.wsola.getOverlap());

        panelbuttons.wsola.setDispatcher(panelbuttons.dispatcher);
        panelbuttons.dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(panelbuttons.wsola);
        panelbuttons.dispatcher
                .addAudioProcessor(panelbuttons.rateTransposer);

        panelbuttons.dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(panelbuttons.gain);

        //panelbuttons.dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(new VolumeDetector(this));

        panelbuttons.dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(panelbuttons.audioPlayer);

        Thread t = new Thread(panelbuttons.dispatcher);
        t.start();
    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How can one avoid the freezing, and make it instantly responsive without time gaps?

I know stop() is deprecated, but does that cause the freezing?

Please ask me for more clarifications, if needed

**SUMMARY - Basic question: 
 How can one stop a runnable and start a new one with zero freezing ?**

Comment: What is your Timer class doing?

Comment: With Timer, startFile0() method is executed after 400 milliseconds. That time is needed for the previous  Dispatcher runnable to be released completely

Comment: Why you are using thread here.

Comment: @UVM The TarsosDSP package allows the audio feedback function, only if i use it's thread Dispatcher.